# display random mysql results whilst limiting them 0,12 and 12,24?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using two functions here, `get_user_set1` and `get_user_set2`.

On my page I have `div1` that displays 12 users, and then `div2` which also displays 12 users. I have 24 users all together.

What I am trying to do is display all 24 users across the 2 divs so 12 in each. at the moment I have `Limit 0`, 12 for the first function and then 12, 24 for the second which displays the first 12 users in the first div and then the second function which displays the next 12 users in the second div.

However, I am trying to figure out how I can make the order in which the 24 users are displayed random without creating a duplicate user and whilst still displaying each of the 24 users and still limiting it to 12. can someone please show me how could I do this?

Thanks.

```
function 1: 

function get_user_set1() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\"
                        AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
                        AND ptb_users.subscription = \"Free\"
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 0 , 12";
            $get_user_set1 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($get_user_set1);
            return $get_user_set1;
        }
function 2:

        function get_user_set2() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\"
                        AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\"
                        AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
                        AND ptb_users.subscription = \"Free\"
                        ORDER BY RAND()
                        LIMIT 12 , 24";
            $get_user_set2 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($get_user_set2);
            return $get_user_set2;
        }
```

Comment: LIMIT 12, 24 will return 24 rows if there.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is very slow for large tables, even if you only need a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Every `ORDER BY RAND()` gives you a different randomly ordered set of users, so asking for the "next" 12 users with a second query is meaningless — you get the next 12 users from a different random order.

If what you really want to do is display 24 users in two sets of 12, do a single `SELECT` with a `LIMIT 24`, and cut the set in half.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one query, and when you do your loop to show each one, you can control with "IF" inside your loop, if the the iterator is smaller than 12 or not and print it in the correct DIV. If you need more detail, please, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder why u have two functions , you could do just one query and control it by the limit variable.

```
         "SELECT *
                    FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
                    WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\"
                    AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\"
                    AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
                    AND ptb_users.subscription = \"Free\"
                    ORDER BY RAND()
                     $limit ";
                        ^---------limit variable here
```

something like this

```
 if (something here ){$limit = 'LIMIT 0,12'; }
 if (something else){$limit = 'LIMIT 12,24';}
```

Comment: Is this actually an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making two queries, make the following query once:

```
SELECT *
FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\"
AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\"
AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
AND ptb_users.subscription = \"Free\"
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0 , 24
```

Use PHP to display the first twelve rows of the result in one div and the last twelve rows in another div.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have two divisions of users.  You want 12 chosen randomly from each and then you want to present them randomly.

The following does this, by using subqueries for each group and then union'ing them together and randomly ordering them:

```
select *
from ((SELECT *
       FROM ptb_users join
            ptb_profiles
            on ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
       WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" and
             ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" and
             ptb_users.subscription = \"Free\" and
             DIVISION = DIV1
       ORDER BY RAND() 
       limit 12
      ) union all
      (SELECT *
       FROM ptb_users join
            ptb_profiles
            on ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id
       WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" and
             ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" and
             ptb_users.subscription = \"Free\" and
             DIVISION = DIV2
       ORDER BY RAND() 
       limit 12
      )
    ) t
ORDER BY RAND()
```